# Ruby on Rails Error on StaticPages GET web pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

bundle exec rails route:

```
                                     root GET    /                                                                                                 static_pages#home
                                    help GET    /help(.:format)                                                                                   static_pages#help
                                   about GET    /about(.:format)                                                                                  static_pages#about
```

rails test:

```
require "test_helper"

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  # def setup
  #   @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  #   end

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

config/routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # get 'static_pages/home', :as => '#home'
  # get 'static_pages/help', :as => 'help'
  # get 'static_pages/about', :as => 'about'
  resources :microposts
  resources :users
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"

  #The root application from before
  # root "application#hello"

  #The root application which leads to the user page
  # root 'users#index'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get', as: :help
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get', as: :about
end
```

The test error:

```
Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_help_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00007fc936aefb08>
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_about_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00007fc9369c08e0>
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_home_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00007fc93698cd10>
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Gem file:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.2.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4", ">= 7.0.4.2"

#bootstrap
gem "bootstrap", "~> 5.2.0"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Comment: The url namespace is different than you are using in tests
Try using `help_url, root_url(for home) or about_url`

Comment: Or just use `rails routes` in the console from your app's directory to see how the actual routes are named. You can also update your `routes.rb` file with as: to alias a route with whatever name you prefer.